# Create a list with items from first group

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am using a list collection with two properties Name and Group.
I need to create a list collection which it will contain only elements from first group, then another list with elements from the second group and finally the third group.

My code:

```
 public class Person
 {
     public string  Name { get; set; }
     public string Group { get; set; }
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        var mItems = new List<Person>();
        mItems.Add(new Person{ Name="A", Group="1", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "B", Group = "1", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "C", Group = "2", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "D", Group = "2", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "E", Group = "3", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "F", Group = "3", });
        mItems.Add(new Person { Name = "G", Group = "1", });

  }
```

I need to create a list with elements which are on the first group, example group "1".( i notice that this is an example, i don't  not know the exactly group name in my application, it can be anything)
So my expected result is a list with A,B and G, then a second list with C,D and finally a third list with E,F. I have found code below:

```
   var results = mItems.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Group).FirstOrDefault());
```

But i am taking the exactly oposite result. I am taking only the first element of each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place your [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) call *after* your [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) as it's currently inside of the select, which is causing the first of each group to be selected:

```
var results = mItems.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Group))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Likewise, if you wanted to output *every* group, you could just remove the `FirstOrDefault()` call altogether. This would return a collection of ordered collections, which you could access individually via the [`ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8) function:

```
var results = mItems.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Group))
                    .ElementAt(someIndex);
```

### Example

You can [see a working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zGSpLg).

Comment: Thank you Rion, it really worked! But how i can do the same for second and third list?

Comment: If you wanted each individual list, you could just remove the `FirstOrDefault()` altogether, which would give you a collection of ordered collections. Once you have that, you could use the [`ElementAt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8) to specify a certain index or simply loop through the items in the collection to output each.

Comment: Thank you Rion it works very well !! Is it possible to ignore group by and use only order by?

Comment: Sure, you could just use an [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) call followed by a [`ThenBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8)` call, with the first passing in your Name, etc.

Comment: Thank you, is there any possibility to ignore exception if index is bigger than the collection?

Comment: You could use `ElementAtOrDefault()` which would return null if the element is not found.